# Adding a checkbox to a button

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm currently porting a WinCE app over to Android (using Xamarin Android) and there is a button with a checkbox in it (don't ask - it's a legacy thing).

Is it possible to create a custom android button that has a checkbox (with text) in Android Studio and bring it over to Xamarin Android or do it directly in my Xam.Android XML layout code?

Comment: Please show us what you mean

Comment: You have a button (say 200 x 100 in size for arguments sake). The byutton has some normal text ("click me") with a standard click event attached. Inside the button though is a checkbox (also with some text) and an event for when the checkbox is clicked

Comment: You said that you have a WinCE app. It is recommended you can post the image to show us what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using Material3, follow the guide here on how to implement it: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#icon